# change css style using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

hi
in my php application i want to change the style using javascript

```
<div id="middle-cnt" class="ad-image-wrapper"><div class="ad-image" style="width: 1000px; height: 450px; top: 0px; left: 131px;"><img height="450" width="1000" src="images/Gallery2/4.jpg"><p class="ad-image-description" style="width: 1000px; bottom: 0px;"><table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td class="image-desc">Stevie III &ndash; 36" long x 24" wide - Oil on Canvas<div style="color: rgb(187, 167, 0); padding-left: 10px; position: absolute; top: 0pt; left: 450px; font-size: 35px; letter-spacing: 6px;">SOLD</div></td></tr></tbody></table></p></div></div>
```

In the baove code i want to change the div style left:0px  ie `<div id="middle-cnt" class="ad-image-wrapper" ><div class="ad-image" style="width: 1000px; height: 450px; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><img ..`

I am using the script below.

```
function fnshowgallery(){
var elm=document.getElementById('middle-cnt').childNodes;

    var divElm=elm[0];
    divElm.style.Left='0px';


}
```

But it's not get the desired result.

Does any one know this?

But i don't know how.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? One thing, it has to be `left` not `Left`.

Comment: why not try using jquery or any other js framework? it should be easier: jquery example: $("div").css("left", "0px")

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("middle-cnt").childNodes[0].style.left = "0px";
```

This should work, if it doesn't, please double-check your DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

The element needs a **position**-property too, if you want the **left**-property to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

javascript is a case sensitive language. and it's camel case. So it's not **Left** but **left. It has to be:

```
divElm.style.left='0px';
```

Answer (score 0):

If I evaluate that javascript in my console with that HTML snippet, it works; the "left" styling is changed to 0px.

**But**, I think you need to have the parent (#middle-cnt) to have `position:relative`, and your  div (.ad-image) with `position:absolute`. Maybe you have this in your stylesheet...

Might help if you say what browser(s) you have tested with, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manipulate the CSS directly with JavaScript it's usually a better approach to *only* use JavaScript to set the CSS class name and leave all your CSS in your .css files. For example:

```
/* CSS */
.foo {
    height:450px;
    left:0;
    position:relative; /* or maybe absolute? */
    top:0;
    width:1000px;
}
```

Then change your JavaScript to something like:

```
var elm = document.getElementById('middle-cnt').childNodes[0];
if (elm) {
    var cssClass = (elm.className) ? ' foo' : 'foo';
    elm.className += cssClass;
}
```

Then, if you need to make any more changes to your CSS you shouldn't need to touch the Javascript.

But for the `left` property to work in your CSS you'll need to set the `position` property to either `relative` or `absolute`.